# OAuth2.0 Credentials from Mule Service

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule

I want to pass OAuth2.0 authorization credential from my Mule service flow to integrate it with FitBit API.

When I am trying to consume FitBit API from PostMan, there is a provision of "Get New Access Token" which asks user to pass
1) Auth URL 2) Access Token URL 3) Client ID 4) Client Secret (FYI -all these credentials would be generated by FitBit).

My issue here is, I am not sure how these credentials would be passed from Mule?

Can any one please help me to provide some pointer please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your situation is the same as [the Github API example](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/authentication-in-http-requests#oauth2-authorization-code) in the MuleSoft docs.

Configure the Mule client app for accessing the FitBit API like the example shows for accessing the Github API:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" basePath="/github"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="api.github.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
    <oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type clientId="27...df" clientSecret="ae...6" redirectionUrl="http://localhost:8082/callback">
        <oauth2:authorization-request authorizationUrl="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize" localAuthorizationUrl="http://localhost:8082/login" />
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token">
            <oauth2:token-response accessToken="#[payload.'access_token']" refreshToken="#[payload.'access_token']"/>
        </oauth2:token-request>
    </oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type>
</http:request-config>
<flow name="oauth-grant-codeFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/user" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Accept" value="application/vnd.github.v3+json"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0 %output application/json
            ---
            payload]]>
       </dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for offering help! Let me try out suggested scenario. Will revert back with in case of any query/ies.

Comment: I tried following the instruction given on Mule soft you have provided, but when I am trying to deploy my application, it is giving me some TLS error,
|
|
|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a listener for http without a TLS context provided
 at org.mule.module.http.api.listener.HttpListenerBuilder.resolveListenerConfig(HttpListenerBuilder.java:268)
 at org.mule.module.http.api.listener.HttpListenerBuilder.build(HttpListenerBuilder.java:195)
Can you please provide some pointer?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I see some browser requirements, like TLS certificate info, specified on the Fitbit site https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/. What browser are you using? Have you followed the Fitbit steps for the Authorization Code Grant Flow?

Comment: I do remember seeing a TLS context error when trying to connect to Github and the error message was misleading (to me as a newbee). The problems  actually turned out to be mistakes in registering the client app on the Github server and in setting the options on the Authentication tab of the Mule HTTP Request Configuration. Pls check your Fitbit registration info against the options on the Authentication tab (compare the Github example).

Comment: many thanks for providing me guidance and sharing your experience. I found the issue, it was my company's fire wall which was forcing me to provide TSL/SSL certificate info. Once I by passed, that error got resolved. From Anypoint I am able to atleast navigate to authorization page. But strange thing is when I click "Allow" button, I am getting below error in Anypoint console.

Comment: 2017-01-18 17:07:45,973 [[oauth-grant-code].auto-generated-listener-config-0.worker.03] ERROR org.mule.module.oauth2.internal.authorizationcode.AutoAuthorizationCodeTokenRequestHandler - Message payload is {"errors":[{"errorType":"invalid_client","message":"Invalid authorization header format. Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process."}],"success":false}

Comment: Maddy, maybe scopes are the problem. Did you select scopes from https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/ (see Scope section) and list them in the Mule HTTP Request Configuration on the Authentication tab (see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/authentication-in-http-requests#using-scopes)? If this is not the problem, let me know and I'll research the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error while trying to connect with Channeladvisor API.This error comes only when you try to use HTTPS . The solution of this issue is to configure you TLS/SSL setting. Install new certificate for the same.

Thanks,
-Dev

Comment: Hi Dev, have you got any solution for ChannelAdvisor API, please suggest git link for demo purpose for same